# Error in read.csv with colClasses: scan() expected 'a real' got 'NULL'

Tags: r, csv, import

I am reading in large csv file using `read.csv`. Several websites suggest using colClasses to define the classes for each column to make the import process faster.

```
t = read.csv("pca.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses = classes)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'a real', got 'NULL'

classes = c("numeric","integer")
```

I obviously have nulls in some of my data.  Is there a way to use colClasses where "numeric" or "integer" include nulls? Also, any other tips on importing large datasets faster into R would be very helpful.  I have all the data in a SQL database and I've tried using RODBC which is surprisingly slower than read.csv().

Comment: Better not to use the variable 't', as it corresponds to the transpose function.  Ditto for 'c'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `na.strings='NULL'` in your call to `read.csv`.

Comment: What does this do?